# INSERT в mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysql

Предположим есть запрос

```
INSERT INTO writer_disciplines_temp(wrd_id,wrt_id)
  SELECT min(id) as wrd_id, wrt_id
  FROM `writer_disciplines`
  WHERE wrt_id = 191000
  GROUP BY discipline_id;
INSERT INTO writer_disciplines_temp(wrd_id,wrt_id)
  SELECT min(id) as wrd_id, wrt_id
  FROM `writer_disciplines`
  WHERE wrt_id = 191000
  GROUP BY discipline_id;
```

Только INSERT-ов на самом деле, допусти 1000.

Для выполнения используется метод

```
public function multiQuery($query_text)
    {
        $return = [];
        $query = mysqli_multi_query($this->getConnection(), $query_text);
        if ($query) {
            do {
                if ($result = mysqli_store_result($this->getConnection())) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        $return[] = $row;
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            } while (mysqli_more_results($this->getConnection()) && mysqli_next_result($this->getConnection()));

        }
        if (mysqli_error($this->getConnection())) {
            die(mysqli_error($this->getConnection()));
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

После INSERT-a сразу выполняется другая операция с нашей таблицей.

Нужно чтобы след команды выполнялись после всех insertoв в multiQuery($sql).($sql указан выше).

Решение найти не смог в рамках использования такого запроса и mysqli_multi_query.
Изменил процесс работы, всё ок. Но, думаю, полезно будет разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема в $this->getConnection(). Если каждый раз открывается новое соединение, то вся последующая обработка не работает. Соответственно, результаты работы всех инсертов мы не получаем. И в результате последующие команды исполняются до того как все запросы на вставку успеют завершиться

В любом случае следует понимать, что mysqli_multi_query - это очень сложный инструмент, с которым надо уметь обращаться. И без нужды не применять. Так что текущее измененное решение без mysqli_multi_query это самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Именно для того чтобы его правильно использовали я и написал пост. Во благо сообщества.

Comment: Информации с INSERT мало